# If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, and $W$ is a subspace of $V$, prove that $\dim(W) \leq \dim(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

My attempt at the proof:

Let $w_1, ..., w_n$ be a basis for $W$. Since $w_1, ..., w_n$ is a linearly independent set in $V$, we can extend it to a basis $B$ of $V$, where $B = \{w_1, ..., w_n, v_1, ..., v_s\}$, where $n+s \geq n$.

Therefore $\dim(W) \leq \dim(V)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: That's a good strategy, but keep in mind that $s$ might be $0$.

Comment: If $s$ is 0, do we not just get $\dim(W) =\dim(V)$?

Comment: That proof is correct, but it presupposes two things : 1. The incomplete basis theorem, which states that one can extend any linearly independent family to a basis; 2. A subspace of a finite dimensional vector space is finite dimensional. Many students don't know how to prove these two facts and take them for granted. If you know how to prove them, then great. Otherwise, I suggest you try ;)

Comment: @Max I can prove the first, I will try the 2nd. Thanks ;)

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Yes, but what you wrote down doesn't make sense when $s=0$, so that case needs to be handled with care.